# How can I extract cheque amount from cheque images?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, text-extraction

I am trying to extract the cheque amount (underlined text in Input Image) from cheque images. I am trying to do this in the following 2 steps:

1. Locate the rectangle box of the amount in the image.
2. Perform OCR using OCR libraries like Tesseract OCR and get the text.

I tried to locate the rectangle box but it is locating so many things from the image.

How can we approach this problem? If anyone has a different approach to extract the amount then please guide me.

**My Code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("Ex2.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('detected.jpg',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Input Image**
[image: input image]

**Currently, I am getting this.**

[image: detected image]

Comment: That is because searching for contours naturally gives you all contours and not only rectangular ones. Besides -  arent those cheques standardized such that the box with the amount always has the same position? That would make locating the box completely unnessecary.

Comment: You can not achieve that easily because its hand-written and not clear.